# Near jump or call to different CS

Tags: assembly, tasm

sorry , I'm a beginner to assembly , so I got an error when i try to jump in TASM , I wanted to set color of these pixels to blue , but i got these errors , please help me
so this is my code:

```
data_here segment
    px dw 0
    py dw 0
ends

stack segment
    dw   128  dup(0)
ends

code segment

start:
; set segment registers:
    ;mov ax, data_here
    ;mov ds, ax
    ;mov es, ax

    assume ds:data_here   
;80x*60y 640*480
mov ax,012h
int 10h

ppos1:
mov al, 1
mov cx, px
mov dx, py
mov ah, 0ch
int 10h
inc px
cmp px,59
jne ppos1
inc py    
cmp py,5
jne ppos1    

mov ah,7
int 21h

int 20h


ends

end start
```

and this is TASM result:

```
-------------
12/20/2017 12:27:35 AM :     Assembling file - C:\cxcc.asm
12/20/2017 12:27:37 AM :     Turbo Assembler  Version 4.1  Copyright (c) 1988, 1996 Borland International
12/20/2017 12:27:37 AM :     
12/20/2017 12:27:37 AM :     Assembling file:   cxcc.asm
12/20/2017 12:27:37 AM :     *Warning* cxcc.asm(7) Reserved word used as symbol: STACK
12/20/2017 12:27:37 AM :     **Error** cxcc.asm(32) Near jump or call to different CS
12/20/2017 12:27:37 AM :     **Error** cxcc.asm(35) Near jump or call to different CS
12/20/2017 12:27:37 AM :     Error messages:    2
12/20/2017 12:27:37 AM :     Warning messages:  1
12/20/2017 12:27:37 AM :     Passes:            1
12/20/2017 12:27:37 AM :     Remaining memory:  468k
12/20/2017 12:27:37 AM :
```

thanks for help.thanks for help.

Comment: Rename stack `stack segment` to something else like `mystack segment` or so and see if the error persists.

Comment: thanks the warning got away but jumps are still there.

Comment: `assume cs:code, ds:data_here` ? (and you have commented out `ds` setup, so the `assume` directive is lying to the TASM about `ds`, not true)  edit: the `assume segment_reg:xyz` directive doesn't emit any code or instructions to CPU, it's other way, it's programmer telling the assembler, that at the point of `assume` directive the value in `segment_reg` is expected to be `xyz`. So if you comment out `ds` setup, and then you say `assume ds:data_here`, you will confuse TASM when it will compile instruction accessing `data_here` symbols, like `mov cx,px`. Then the compiled offset will be wrong.

Comment: You didn't put the _CS_ in your assume. Modify it to something like `assume cs:code, ds:data_here` . I noticed that ped7g commented at same time. You got your answer twice.

Comment: thanks it can assemble but didn't change the color of pixels

Comment: it can assemble but  not changing color of any pixel

Comment: Yeah, that's quite normal with assembly, compile time errors should be easy to fix if you follow your assembler documentation, and syntax definitions, it's rarely worth an SO question. But the code often doesn't do what you expect, because it always does exactly what you write into code, it doesn't care about your intents and dreams. And that's how SO questions work, one problem per question. Your Q was syntax compile time error, nobody bothered to verify if your code makes sense or logic. Now you can try in turbo debugger what it does, if before calling `int 10h` all regs have correct values.

Comment: Actually as I told you, that you lie to TASM about `ds`, that may easily be source of your problem, that `mov cx,px` is not loading value from correct memory for you, so you end with who-knows-what value in `cx`, not `0`. Did you fix this one too?

Comment: so sorry it worked , I forgot that i have commented that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fully fixed code of yours (with some guessing, what did you want), and somewhat more extensive use of directives, read from http://www.ousob.com/ng/masm/ng3e51c.php (I have somewhere also original TASM books which were in package, but no idea where they did end, probably in some box inside some bigger box, placed very close to the previous millennium... need to call archaeologists probably)

```
.MODEL SMALL
data_here SEGMENT USE16 PAGE MEMORY
    px dw 0
    py dw 0
ENDS

my_stack SEGMENT USE16 PAGE STACK
    dw   128  dup(0)
ENDS

my_code SEGMENT USE16 PARA PUBLIC

    ASSUME cs:my_code, ss:my_stack
start:
; set segment registers:
    mov ax, data_here
    mov ds, ax
    ASSUME ds:data_here

    ;80x*60y 640*480
    mov ax,012h
    int 10h

    xor bh,bh       ; page number for pixel write = 0
ppos1:
    mov ax, 0C01h   ; ah = 0C (write pixel), al = 1 (blue color)
    mov cx, [px]
    mov dx, [py]
    int 10h
    inc word ptr [px]
    cmp word ptr [px],59
    jne ppos1
    mov word ptr [px],0
    inc word ptr [py]
    cmp word ptr [py],5
    jne ppos1

    ; wait for console input without echo
    mov ah,7
    int 21h
    ; restore text mode
    mov ax,3
    int 10h
    ; terminate EXE through int 21,4C (int 20h works for COM files)
    mov ah,4Ch
    int 21h

ENDS

END start
```

And how would my version look - avoiding extremely slow BIOS write pixel, and using 80386 instructions (32b registers):

(`dosbox 0.74` which I'm using as DOS emulator supports CPU up to 80586 (Pentium), and 386 emulation is very very solid, 486 is fine too AFAIK, 586 is more experimental ... now I'm not sure, if there's not a glimpse of "686" ("core duo" was it? Intel didn't use "686" any more as numbers can't be registered as (tm), pity, the number scheme was much more clear than current four generations of "i7" CPU on market, not being sure which is latest without research), but I think it's far from working, if it's there)

```
.MODEL SMALL
data_here SEGMENT USE16 PAGE MEMORY
ENDS

my_stack SEGMENT USE16 PAGE STACK
    dw   1024  dup(0)
ENDS

my_code SEGMENT USE16 PARA PUBLIC
.386

    ASSUME cs:my_code, ss:my_stack
start:
    ; init environment
    mov ax, data_here
    mov ds, ax
    ASSUME ds:data_here
    mov ax,0A000h
    mov es,ax       ; es = VRAM segment for direct VRAM writes
    ;640x480 16 colour mode
    mov ax,012h
    int 10h

    ; draw 59x5 rectangle [0, 0] -> [58, 4] with blue color (1)
    mov dx,03C4h    ; dx = VGA control index register
    mov ax,0102h    ; INDEX = MASK MAP, MASK = 0x01 (blue bitplane)
    out dx,ax       ; other planes are zeroed by mode change
                    ; so I will modify only blue bitplane
    xor di,di       ; initial address to write
    mov dx,5        ; number of lines to fill
    mov eax,0FFFFFFFFh   ; fill value with pixel bits (all set)
fill_line:
    ; 59 pixels = 7 full bytes (8 bits), and 3 bits in last 8th byte
    stosd           ; 4 bytes written
    stosw           ; 6 bytes written
    stosb           ; 7 bytes written
    ; patch remaining 3 bits (3 pixels) of 8th byte
    mov bl,es:[di]  ; read VRAM
    or  bl,0E0h     ; set top 3 bits of old value
    mov es:[di],bl  ; write it back to VRAM
    ; actually mov byte ptr es:[di],0E0h would work too, because clear screen
    ; but this is also showing how set bit to 1 works with OR
    add di,640/8-7  ; advance DI to next line
    dec dx
    jnz fill_line

    ; wait for console input without echo
    mov ah,7
    int 21h
    ; restore text mode
    mov ax,3
    int 10h
    ; terminate EXE through int 21,4C (int 20h works for COM files)
    mov ah,4Ch
    int 21h

ENDS

END start
```

Tested with TASM 4.1 and TLINK 7.1.30.1 in DOSBOX 0.74, like:

```
C:\>TASM TEST_EXE
  ... TASM output ...
C:\>TLINK TEST_EXE
  ... TLINK output (just version + copyright)
C:\>TEXT_EXE.EXE
  .. switches to gfx mode and draws small blue rectangle, waits for some key, exits to DOS (restoring text mode)...
```

The VGA 12h mode VRAM access knowledge (how to set blue bitplane) taken from http://www.wagemakers.be/english/doc/vga (not sure about total quality of that article, I basically knew exactly what I was looking for (just the VGA control port number + which bit is mask), still recalling how the 16 colour modes VRAM is organized and what I need to write there, so I didn't read the whole article.

Comment: My Turbo C 2.01 Professional Books still have a spot on my archive shelves: https://imgur.com/a/UKgrh

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Lovely. I'm pretty sure I had turbo assembler **instruction** reference guide somewhere at hand recently (2008+ did seen it and listed through), but it definitely didn't look as good as yours, did look lot more like kind of salad, with the wire binding holding on many pages just in remaining 5-10 holes, others torn away. Other books look probably same as yours, if they still exist somewhere, didn't use those on daily basis for 5+ years. :D

Comment: Just as a note this code requires at least a 386 processor. I'd probably make that explicit with a `.386` directive at the top (for readability). I only mention this if someone were to try this on something that supports a processor earlier than a 386 and didn't look through the code fully.Edit: Oops I see the `.386` buried later on ;-).

Comment: @MichaelPetch: the `.386` directive is under code segment definition. (it may be used right AFTER `.model` directive, but I personally prefer to have it in code segment). Interestingly it may be not AHEAD of `.model`, as the TASM doesn't then know if it means protected mode 80386, or real mode 80386.

Comment: See my comment edit ;-). I'd still mention this fact in your answer description (I already upvoted so such an edit won't change my overall opinion). Was just an observation.