# DOS Console data memory access when 32bit registers are accessible assemblery

Tags: windows, assembly, memory, dos, tasm

I'm working on a project in TASM assembly and I have problems outputing color to specific cells of the DOS console when I use 32 bit registers in assembler (with `.386`).

Here's an example of how I would normally do that:

BX loc of cell,
AH color / char of cell

```
mov ah , 01000000b ; Color Red to ah
mov ax,0b800h ; memory location of the console 
mov es,ax ; to es 
mov es:[bx] , ah ; mov data from ah to the cell of bx
```

this works but when I do `.386` at the start to make it 32 bit this code stops working ... anyone know a way to fix the problem ?
 SHORT : 
The code need to set Color to cell .  works without `.386` and stops working with `.386`

Code segments :

```
.386
.Model small
.data 
 ;all my data 
 .code 
  Start:
  ; all the code in there also the output code snippet I showed 
 end start
```

---

Fix by Ped7g : 
put the line `.386` inside the `.code` segment

Fix by Margaret Bloom : 
add `USE16` modifier to `MODEL` directive

Both are working. Thanks for the help

*tasm 
32 bit*

Comment: Don't think `.386` makes anything 32 bit and should work just the same. It just specifies you have 386+ instructions avalilable.

Comment: For a true dos console program, you need to use a 16 bit assembler, that produces 16 bit real mode code. That 16 program can use 32 bit registers and memory accesses using 32 bit offsets from a segment register should work. This is similar to how Windows 3.1 winmem32 works, although WatCom 10.0 C++ is (was) one of the few tool sets that includes winmem32 as one of it's programming models (the others don't support it directly and require assembly code routines).

Comment: @rcgldr I use .386 to access the 32bit registers . can you point out what is the problem in the code and why it’s not working with .386 and working without ?

Comment: @TomZe - the example code in the question is 16 bit code. Please add example 32 bit code. Are you sure the tool set is building a 16 bit dos console program (.COM or .EXE)?

Comment: @rcgldr ok made an edit to make it clearer . It’s not about 32 bit or 16 bit . It’s  about why it stops working when I do .368 (I have to do it to access 32 bit registers)

Comment: "It’s about why it stops working when I do .368"...Maybe because the segment registers are not properly set up. IIRC 386 requires some kind of [_Protected Mode_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protected_mode#386_additions_to_protected_mode) to function.

Comment: @zx485 ok can yo provide a replacement code that you think should work if that’s the problem ?

Comment: No, I can't. You don't get the problem. Did you even read the link I provided?

Comment: @zx485 Yes I did read the Wikipedia link . Can you explain what I don’t get ?

Comment: The problem is, that you used `.386` too soon (will make your `.code` directive to define 32b protected mode code segment -> wrong instruction opcodes for 16b real mode). If you would first specify `.model`, and then `.code` segment, then using `.386` inside the `.code` segment will be processed differently (code segment will be already set to 16b real mode code, and the .386 will just allow for 32b ins.). The `.dotDirectives` are simplified shortcuts to set up common things in common way, so they may break if you use them in wrong order, or mix together with full `segment` directive/etc..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Near jump or call to different CS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47895164/near-jump-or-call-to-different-cs)

Comment: and... from your question it is not clear, that you fully understand the difference between 16b real mode and 32b protected mode. Are you sure you want to use 32b mode instructions? Then your `.386` was correct, and the code stops working, because you didn't switch to protected mode, and execute it as such (and in protected mode you can map the video memory to flat memory addressing map, so no need to use segments then, just `mov ebx,0B8000h` - but that means you already wrote small own OS or you use DOS extender). IMO it's more likely you want to stay in 16b real mode, and use 32b inst./regs.

Comment: @Ped7g - in the case of Masm 6.11 - part of a 16 bit tool set from Microsoft, it won't matter where the .386 is, as Masm 6.11 will only generate 16 bit real mode code with 386 prefixes as needed to work with 32 bit registers in 16 bit real mode. I was unaware that the same version of Tasm could produce either 16 bit or 32 bit code based on where the .386 directive is located.

Comment: @Ped7g you’re also right this fix also works ! Thanks you

Comment: `mov ax,0b800h` clobbers AH, so `mov es:[bx] , ah` is storing the upper byte of the segment value.  Either use `mov es:[bx] , 01000000b` or set `AH` *after* you're done with AX, or use different registers.

Comment: @PeterCordes oh I think you’re right on that one luckily. this was done in the correct order in my program and only done wrong in my example .

Comment: Ah, that explains why you said it worked.  Either you hadn't noticed it was the wrong colour, or your real code was different somehow.

Comment: @PeterCordes yea my real code in about 700 lines so I have only written the output mechanism in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't specify the attributes of the code segment(s) explicitly the use of the `.386` directive will set the default operand side to 32-bit.

Quoting the [TASM manual](http://bitsavers.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/pdf/borland/turbo_assembler/Turbo_Assembler_Version_5_Users_Guide.pdf):

> Note that you can specify the model modifier in two places, for compatibility with
>   MASM 5.2. If you don't use a model specifier, Turbo Assembler as.sumes the
>   NEARSTACK modifier, and USE32 (if the 80386 or 80486 processor is selected).

This doesn't mean that you are allowed to use 32-bit registers<sup>1</sup> but that the assembler will emit the instructions in a "specular" way.

All code in an x86 machine has a default operand size.
When running in 32-bit it is 32 bits, when running in 16-bit it is 16 bits (64-bit is a bit more involved, it is still 32 bits but can be overridden with the REX.W prefix).

The default operand size determines the default size of the immediate operands, i.e. the number of bytes that follow an opcode of an instruction that expects a value.

Instructions like `mov ax, 0b800h` and `mov eax, 0b800h` are encoded the *same* way: with the opcode `B8`.
After this opcode, it follows the immediate operand of 16 or 32 bits.
The specific size depends on the default operand size.

To access the "other" size, i.e. specify a 16-bit version of an instruction in 32-bit code and vice-versa, an operand size override prefix exists (value `66`).

Put on a table

```
                    +-----------------------------------------+
                    |           Default operand size          | 
+-------------------+---------------------+-------------------+ 
|Instruction        |      16             |        32         |
+-------------------+---------------------+-------------------+
|                   |                     |                   |
|mov ax, 1234h      |     B8 34 12        |    66 B8 34 12    |  
|                   |                     |                   |
|mov eax, 12345678h |  66 B8 78 56 34 12  |   B8 78 56 34 12  |   
|                   |                     |                   |
+-------------------+---------------------+-------------------+
```

See how `mov ax, 0b800h` is encoded with `66 B8` when the assembler assumes a default operand size of 32-bit?
And that when executed in a 16-bit code the `66 B8` is decoded has having a 32-bit immediate?

This screw up the decoding of subsequent instructions.

The snipped posted when *assembled as 32-bit code* but *executed as 16-bit code* result in:

```
00000000  B440              mov ah,0x40
00000002  66B800B88EC0      mov eax,0xc08eb800
00000008  26678827          mov [es:edi],ah
```

## How to solve this problem

Give each code segment the code-size attribute explicitly or set the default one with the `MODEL` directive.
For example, if you use a `SMALL` memory model:

```
.MODEL USE16 SMALL
```

---

<sup>1</sup> You always are as far as the CPU is concerned, it's just that TASM refuses to assemble instructions not compliant with the processor family chosen.

Comment: I of course have a MODEl directive in my code this is just a code snippet of the problematic part of a match longer code , this output thing is in my” .code “ segment  . I just don’t want to waste people time by posting all my code ...

Comment: @TomZe It seems you are missing the `USE16` modifier in your `MODEL` directive.

Answer (score 2):

Before you can use any possibilities of x86 protected mode (either its 16 bit or 32 bit variants), you must run certain group of machine instructions that transfer the CPU from real mode to protected mode. It is a not trivial thing, as you need to set up at least a minimal number of system tables and system registers, such as CR0. It is well described in the Intel Software Developer Manual [Volume 3](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdm#combined) with examples in assembler.

Note that literally everything changes in processor's behavior after that: instructions that you've wrote as input to assembler will no longer mean what they meant (because the default operand and address sizes might have changed), but most importantly memory addresses no longer simply point to physical memory but instead are transformed through segmentation and paging. Even your console address has to be recalculated to be sure that you point to right physical address. Note that good old DOS interrupts will no longer work because they are written to work in real mode and do not expect protected mode; it will simply hang or reboot.

Maybe you should clarify what you are trying to achieve and why existing real-mode code does not satisfy your needs. If your goal is learning, then I suggest you make yourself familiar with what a protected mode is, how to transfer the CPU to it, and how to write programs for it. I would estimate the first point would take 80% or your time, the second 15% and the program itself will only take 5% or less of your time.

Comment: The current real mode code doesn’t satisfy my needs because it’s not working when I do .386 at the start of the program that code stops working . Also note that this is of course not my whole program . This is just the output part of a 650 lines program . This is the part that doesn’t work .

Comment: Ok I have added my segment in the edit to make it more clear